# PreloadJS - working version for IE9 and IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, createjs, preloadjs

I am trying to figure out which version of PreloadJS to use that will work in both IE9 and IE11. I'm getting different errors in the browsers depending on which version I'm using - 0.6.1 vs. NEXT. Code is taken straight from the [GitHub ReadMe](https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Loader</title>
    <script src="preloadjs-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function(){
            var preload = new createjs.LoadQueue();
            preload.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileComplete);
            preload.loadFile('load-image.jpg');
            function handleFileComplete(event) {
                document.body.appendChild(event.result);
            }
        }());
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <p>Basic Loader</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Using 0.6.1 in IE11, I get this error for any image I try to load:

```
DOM7001: Invalid argument 'url'. Failed to revoke Blob URL: 'undefined'.
```

Using NEXT works as expected. However, using NEXT in IE9, I get this error:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'loader' is undefined 
preloadjs-NEXT.min.js, line 13 character 14055
```

..and from the non-minified NEXT:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'loader' is undefined 
preloadjs-NEXT.combined.js, line 6324 character 4
```

Is there a PreloadJS version that works across all versions of Internet Explorer (at least 9, 10, 11)?

Comment: This undefined loader error seems to be a legitimate bug in the NEXT code. Looking at submitting an issue in GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and address this ASAP